# Can I write from python (specifically pandas) to Salesforce using the simple_salesforce library?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I have extracted some data from Salesforce using the simple_salesforce library and the REST api. After cleansing and doing some aggregations within pandas, I now want to write the data back to Salesforce using a Salesforce ID as the unique ID for writing the data. Is there a way within simple_salesforce to write the data back to Salesforce, or maybe using the bulk api?

- Python version 3.6 and 3.7
- Windows 10 x64 bit

Thank you!

Comment: I have Faced some issue while connecting salesforce and python .Can you help to resolve this issue .

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance at their github page shows [examples](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce#record-management) of writing back to Salesforce using the syntax,

`sf.sObject.create({'key': 'value', ...})`

or

`sf.Contact.update('ID',{'key': 'value', ...})`

Have you tried this?

Edit: To be clear, writing using a unique ID sounds like you are looking for an update operation. That is the second example I mentioned.